# Flex / Yacc program causing breakpoint on free instruction in VC++

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, yacc, flex-lexer

I have Flex / Yacc program that is causing a breakpoint when it is run in the VC++ 2012 IDE.  The breakpoint occurs on the instruction (in pre_lxr.l below):

```
free(pre_fname);
```

The project contains the lexer (.l file), the yacc file (.y) and an interface file (which sits between the parser and the C++ part of the program).  The problem seems to be related to memory corruption / leak.  See code below (I've included as much relevant code as I think is necessary).  I'm also not sure about the yyterminate call.

```
/* pre_prs_ifc.h */
#define MAX_PRE_ERR 120
#define MAX_BANKS 16
#define MAX_PRES 512

typedef struct
{
    char *bank;
    char *name;
} preStruct;

void initPrePrs();
void appBank(int line_num, const char *name);
void appPre(int line_num, const char *bank, const char *name);
void freePrePrs();

char pre_err[MAX_PRE_ERR];
int num_banks;
int num_pres;
char* pre_fname;
int pre_lnum;
char* bank[MAX_BANKS];
preStruct pre[MAX_PRES];

/* pre_prs_ifc.c */
#include "pre_prs_ifc.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void initPrePrs()
// initialises parser variables
{
    pre_err[0] = 0;
    num_banks = 0;
    num_pres = 0;
    pre_lnum = 1;
}

void appBank(int line_num, const char *name)
{
    if (num_banks < MAX_BANKS)
        bank[num_banks++] = _strdup(name);
    else
        sprintf(pre_err, "Error on line %d: maximum number of banks     
exceeded.", line_num);
}

void appPre(int line_num, const char *bank, const char *name)
{
    if (num_pres < MAX_PRES)
    {
        pre[num_pres].bank = _strdup(bank);
        pre[num_pres++].name = _strdup(name);
    }
    else
        sprintf(pre_err, "Error on line %d: maximum number of presets     
exceeded.", line_num);
}

void freePrePrs()
// frees parser variables
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < num_banks; i++)
        free(bank[i]);
    for (i = 0; i < num_pres; i++)
    {
        free(pre[i].bank);
        free(pre[i].name);
    }
}

/* pre_lxr.l */
%{
    #include "pre_prs_ifc.h"
    #include "pre_prs.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
%}

%option outfile="pre_lxr.c" header-file="pre_lxr.h"
%option prefix="pre"
%option warn reentrant noyywrap never-interactive nounistd bison-bridge
%option debug

%%

"banks"|"BANKS" { return banks; }
"presets"|"PRESETS" { return presets; }

"{" { return l_bracket; }
"}" { return r_bracket; }
";" { return semicolon; }

\"([^\\\"\n]|\\.)+\" {
    yylval->str = (char*)malloc(strlen(yytext) - 1);
    strncpy(yylval->str, &yytext[1], strlen(yytext) - 2);
    return quoted_str;
}

[ \t] { }
[\r\n] { pre_lnum++; }

<<EOF>> {
    free(pre_fname);
    if (!YY_CURRENT_BUFFER)
        yyterminate();
}

%%
int preerror(const char *msg)
{
    sprintf(pre_err, "Error in %s on line %d.", pre_fname, pre_lnum);
    return 0;
}

/* pre_prs.y */
%{
    #include "pre_prs_ifc.h"
    #include "pre_prs.h"
    #include "pre_lxr.h"
    int preerror(yyscan_t scanner, const char *msg);
%}

%code requires
{
    #ifndef YYSCAN_T
        #define YYSCAN_T
        typedef void* yyscan_t;
    #endif
}

%output  "pre_prs.c"
%defines "pre_prs.h"
%name-prefix "pre"
%define api.pure
%lex-param   { yyscan_t scanner }
%parse-param { yyscan_t scanner }
%error-verbose

%union
{
    char ch;
    char* str;
}

%destructor { free($$); } <str>

%token<ch> l_bracket r_bracket semicolon
%token<str> quoted_str
%token<num> banks presets

%%
cmds:
    | cmds cmd
    ;

cmd:
    bank_list
    |
    pre_list
    ;

bank_list:
    banks l_bracket bank_decls r_bracket
    ;

bank_decls:
    | bank_decls bank_decl
    ;

bank_decl:
    quoted_str semicolon
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "append bank %s\n", $1);
        appBank(pre_lnum, $1);
        free($1);
    }
    ;

pre_list:
    presets l_bracket pre_decls r_bracket
    ;

pre_decls:
    | pre_decls pre_decl
    ;

pre_decl:
    quoted_str quoted_str semicolon
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "append preset, bank %s, name %s\n", $1, $2);
        appPre(pre_lnum, $1, $2);
        free($1);
        free($2);
    }
    ;

%%

/* C++ using the above code */
extern "C"
{
    #include "pre_prs_ifc.h"
    #include "pre_prs.h"
    #include "pre_lxr.h"
}
int yyparse(yyscan_t scanner);
...
bool CMainDlg::loadBankPre(std::string fname)
// load bank and preset lists
{
    int err, i;
    yyscan_t scanner;
    FILE *src;
    std::string name_str;
    CListBox* bank_lb;
    bool ret_val;
    pre_fname = _strdup(fname.c_str());
    if (prelex_init(&scanner))
    {
        m_err = "Error initialising scanner.";
        return false;
    }
    src = fopen(fname.c_str(), "r");
    if (src == NULL)
    {
        m_err = "Could not open file: " + fname;
        ret_val = false;
    }
    else
    {
        preset_in(src, scanner);
        initPrePrs();
        err = preparse(scanner);
        if (err)
        {
            m_err = pre_err;
            ret_val = false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (pre_err[0] == 0)
            {
                bank_lb = (CListBox*)GetDlgItem(IDC_LI_BANK);
                for (i = 0; i < num_banks; i++)
                    bank_lb->AddString(bank[i]);
                ret_val = true;
            }
            else
            {
                m_err = pre_err;
                ret_val = false;
            }
        }
        fclose(src);
    }
    pre_delete_buffer(0, scanner);
    prelex_destroy(scanner);
    return ret_val;
}
CMainDlg::~CMainDlg()
// destructor
{
    freePrePrs();
}
```

Comment: If you can run your code under Valgrind, that might pinpoint the error.

Comment: In `strncpy(yylval->str, &yytext[1], strlen(yytext) - 2);` you must terminate the string: `yylval->str[strlen(yytext)-1]= '\0';` That are all the errors I can see.

Comment: Not sure if this is a cause but you have doubled free directives. One is in the `%destructor <str>` and the other in the `bank_decl` and `pre_decl` rule. When you use destructor I don't see a reason to invoke free again...

Comment: OK, I added the line yylval->str[strlen(yytext) - 2] = '\0'.  I'm sure I read somewhere that the destructor is called when there is an error, besides which removing the free instructions from the rules caused more memory leaks (using Visual Leak Detector). I still have the same problem, the program does not seem to like the free in the EOF section.

Comment: @WojciechFrohmberg: flex does not invoke the destructor when the value is passed to a rule. It only invokes it if the value is popped without ever having been used in a reduction (i.e. during error recovery or abnormal exit.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *never* define global variables in a header file. The header file must *declare* them as *extern*, and they need to be *defined* in precisely one translation unit.

As written, each translation unit has its own definition of the global variables, including `pre_fname`. That's undefined behaviour and there is no guarantee that the names used in different translation units refer to the same storage locations. Even better than fixing the declarations would be to pass them through to the parser and scanner so as to avoid using globals.

In any event, `pre_fname` is created (with `strdup`) in CMainDlg::loadBankPre and it makes most sense to also `free` it in the same function, ideally using a smart pointer. In you did that, you wouldn't need an `<<EOF>>` rule at all.

Also, `strncpy` really is not a good idea here. As @PaulOgilvie points out in a comment, it leaves the copied string unterminated, with the consequence that the later `strdup` in `appBank` will copy an undetermined number of extra bytes, possibly referencing invalid memory. (By the way, you don't need to call `strlen` on `yytext`. Flex provides the variable `yyleng` for precisely this purpose, which saves an extra scan over the token.)

On the other hand, when you are formatting into a fixed-length buffer (`sprintf(pre_err...)`), you should use `snprintf` instead. Otherwise you might overrun `pre_err`, which could end up overwriting `pre_fname`.

Also, your prototype for `preerror` does not agree with its definition. So if it is called, something bad will happen.

And finally, your `<<EOF>>` rule (which is unnecessary, see above), does not return 0, so the lexer will keep on trying to scan. `<<EOF>>` rules must either return 0 or provide a new input buffer. (Or otherwise exit.) In this case, since the `<<EOF>>` rule calls `free`, the second (and subsequent) activations of the rule will free the same storage multiple times.

Comment: @tyebillion: Added a couple more instances of UB. I still don't know if any of them are responsible for your memory corruption, but it is possible that there are others.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the EOF section is called over and over resulting in an infinite loop, which can be stopped by including a call to yypop_buffer_state.

```
<<EOF>> {
    yypop_buffer_state(yyscanner);
    free(pre_fname);
    if (!YY_CURRENT_BUFFER)
        yyterminate();
}
```

So the free was causing a crash on the second time around the EOF section.  As rici pointed out though (in this case) the EOF section is not needed at all if the free is moved to the function loadBankPre.

Comment: Oops, missed that problem. An `<<EOF>>` rule must either add a new buffer, call yyterminate or return 0; otherwise, the lexer will keep calling the rule. Returning 0 is the best, but not having an EOF rule at all is even better.